# Why is my app not showing in the grid of icons (not the launcher) after installation

Tags: android, react-native

I recently started testing my react-native android application and noticed that it doesn't create an app icon on installation.  When I debug - it seems to install and run fine, but when I look for it in the app icon to launch - it does not show up.  Looking at the list of installed apps, it's there.  How can I debug this?  Do I need to change the launch mode from `singleTop` to something else?  I tried changing it to `singleInstance` and it still had the same issue.  If I remove some of the intent filters it seems to work - so maybe I messed up the branch.io installation instructions?  Do I need to create a seperate intent filter xml node for the other intents?  https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/react/#android-configure-manifest

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="www.foo.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/event" />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            <data android:scheme="fooapp" android:host="open" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="fcm.ACTION.EVENT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

### Update

Splitting up the intent-filters seems to have fixed it - but a bit unclear if that is the correct thing to do.  In the branch.io instructions - did they mean for me to create a new intent-filter and not add to the existing main one?

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="www.foo.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/event" />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            <data android:scheme="fooapp" android:host="open" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

The launcher is typically specific software developed by the individual hardware manufacturers. On all of the devices i have, an app does not get installed on the homescreen when it is not installed from the play store, but it does show up in the list of apps. However, that behaviour will be specific to the launcher you are using i think.

You should not need to go to settings->apps though just to see it. Is that the problem you are having?

Perhaps a screenshot as well as a description of your test device (s) would make the question clearer.

Update....

Typically the startup activity has one intent filter with only MAIN and LAUNCHER. I would just try to remove the other things from that intent filter and see if that resolves the problem. Then one by one, add the rest of the things you have listed until you identify the problem child.

Looking at this again, I am not sure that you can define 2 actions in a single event filter. So it seems you need to remove VIEW.

Comment: sorry I mis-spoke, not the launcher - but the app list - the app icon is literally no where on the phone except for in settings -> apps.  So yes, that is the problem I'm seeing.  it seems to have somethign to do with my intent filters that I added to support branch.io https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/react/#android-configure-manifest

Comment: Ok, I moved the intent filters from the branch.io instructions to a new intent filter - not sure if that was correct but that seemed to have fixed it.